# Import CSV file in laravel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using `maatwebsite/excel` and I have CSV file including `1449` rows where I have `value` and `parent title` in each row. (here is sample of it)

[image: screen1]

what i want is to get `id` of `parents` from another table and use those id's instead of titles (which i have in my csv)

## Codes

`import function`

```
public function importsku(Request $request) {
      Excel::load($request->file('file'), function($reader) {
        $results = $reader->all();

         foreach($results as $row){
            $findermap = new FinderMap;
            $findermap->ymm_value_id = $row->ymm_value_id;
            $findermap->sku = $row->sku;
            $findermap->save();
        }

        Session::flash('success', 'Your Data imported successfully.');
        return redirect()->route('finders.index');
      });
}
```

## More info

The parents name that I'm looking to get their `id's` are stored in table named **finder_ymm_values** where their **dropdown_id** is `4` *I think this will helps us to limit our search and get results faster*

## Question

What should I add to my import function in order to search for my parents name and get their id's for each value i have?

## UPDATE

I added code below to my import function and now it does get the id's that i'm looking for, but the issue is it gets them in collection.

`code i added`

```
foreach($results as $row){
  //added
  $vals = FinderYmmValue::where('title', $row->ymm_value_id)->where('dropdown_id', '4')->pluck('id');
  $findermap = new FinderMap;
  $findermap->ymm_value_id = $vals; //changed
  $findermap->sku = $row->sku;
  $findermap->save();
}
```

`error i get`

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails .......... insert
>   into `finder_maps` (`ymm_value_id`, `sku`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values ([303], L0R88AA, 2018-06-14 10:41:51, 2018-06-14 10:41:51))

As you can see in last line of my error i get my id as `[303]`

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

here last changes I've made and imported my file successfully.

```
foreach($results as $row){
  $vals = FinderYmmValue::where('title', $row->ymm_value_id)->where('dropdown_id', '4')->pluck('id');
  foreach ($vals as $val) {
    $valid = $val;
  }
  $findermap = new FinderMap;
  $findermap->ymm_value_id = $valid;
  $findermap->sku = $row->sku;
  $findermap->save();
}
```

hope it can help others.